# get complete 'div' content using class name or id using php

Tags: php, html

i got a page source from a file using php and its output is similar to

```
<div class="basic">

 <div class="math">

  <div class="winner">

   <div class="under">

        <div class="checker">

         <strong>check</strong>

        </div>

   </div>

  </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

from this i need to got only a particular 'div' with whole div and contents inside like below when i give input as 'under'(class name) . anybody suggest me how to do this one using php

```
<div class="under">

      <div class="checker">

         <strong>check</strong>

      </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: This got nothing in common with PHP you formerly tagged. Edited.

Comment: I think OP has scraped the above HTML from file / site and now wants to parse it in php. Php tag re-added.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)?

Comment: this is a good question - why has it been so savagely down-voted?

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="basic">
    <div class="math">
        <div class="winner">
            <div class="under">
                <div class="checker">
                    <strong>check</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>;
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="under"]');

$div = $div->item(0);

echo $dom->saveXML($div);
```

This will output:

```
<div class="under">
    <div class="checker">
        <strong>check</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it returns only: check

Answer (score 7):

**Function to extract the contents from a specific div id from any webpage**

The below function extracts the contents from the specified div and returns it. If no divs with the ID are found, it returns false.

```
function getHTMLByID($id, $html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $node = $dom->getElementById($id);
    if ($node) {
        return $dom->saveXML($node);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

`$id` is the ID of the `<div>` whose content you're trying to extract, `$html` is your HTML markup.

Usage example:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.mysql.com/');
echo getHTMLByID('tagline', $html);
```

Output:

```
The world's most popular open source database
```

Comment: @PareshMayani: Why do you think it is inappropriate? It surely answers the question that was asked. Did you even bother to read both the questions? This answer applies to both.

Comment: @PareshMayani, It's the duplicate of his answer , so what ?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you asking but this might be it

```
preg_match_all("<div class='under'>(.*?)</div>", $htmlsource, $output);
```

$output should now contain the inner content of that div

Comment: When we use this above expression it will check for only first closing div not the corresponding closing div for the class..

Comment: you changed your question.. Check out the [link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) With that you should be able to do something like this: $dom = str_get_html($htmlsource); echo $dom->find(".under")->innertext;

Comment: I tried that too but cant able to get the whole div. i can only get the div content using 'textContent'.. do u have any idea in that